# Model building in a for loop in C++ (with Cplex Concert Technology)

Tags: c++, for-loop, environment-variables, cplex

I'm trying to build and solve several models using cplex (`IloCplex`) in C++. I have randomly constructed these three models on paper but I can't construct them in a for loop.

```
Minimize 2x1 + 5x2
S.t. 3x1 + 2x2<=5
x1,x2 >= 0

Minimize x1 + 3x2
S.t. 2x1 + 5x2 >= 3
x1,x2>=0

Minimize 4x1+2x2
s.t. x1 – x2 <= 0
x1,x2>=0
```

Here is a short and simple excerpt of what I'm trying to do.

I am debugging and the error is thrown at `cplex.extract(model);`

I have also tried (in place of that line) `IloCplex cplex(model)` as well; however, that is also throwing the same error. I've also tried having the `IloEnv` and `env.end()` both in and out of the for loop and nothing changes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
ILOSTLBEGIN

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int a[3] = {3,2,1};
    int b[3] = {2,5,-1};
    int c1[3] = {2,1,4};
    int c2[3] = {5,3,2};
    cout << "Hi" <<endl;
    //a = {3,2,1};
    //b = [2,5,-1];
    //c1 = [2,1,4];
    //c2 = [5,3,2];

    IloEnv env;
    IloCplex cplex;
    for(int r=0;r<3;r++){
        cout << "Good" << endl;
        IloModel model(env);
        IloNumVarArray x(env);
        x.add(IloNumVar(env));
        x.add(IloNumVar(env));
        model.add(a[r]*x[0]+b[r]*x[1]);
        model.add(IloMinimize(env, c1[r]*x[0]+c2[r]*x[1]));
        cplex.extract(model);
        cplex.solve();
        cout << "Min= " << cplex.getObjValue() << endl;
        cplex.clear();
        model.end();
    }
    env.end();
}
```

And this is the error message I get when I'm debugging (if that'd be of any help)[If I'm not debugging, it's just aborting]:

```
Unhandled exception at at 0x00007FFA8B667788 in DebugTemplate.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: IloEmptyHandleException at memory location 0x00000003886FF510.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a several problems with your program.  For starters you need to initialize the `cplex` variable with the `IloEnv`:

```
IloCplex cplex(env);
```

Also, with this line:

```
model.add(a[r]*x[0]+b[r]*x[1]);
```

You need to define a `IloRangeArray` for the constraints and add it to that (you are also missing the right-hand side).  For example:

```
IloRangeArray c(env);
c.add(a[r]*x[0]+b[r]*x[1] <= 1);
model.add(c);
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to figure out how to define different right-hand sides depending on `r` (I've hard-coded it to "<= 1" above).

Finally, when debugging, it's always a good idea to add a call to `exportModel` just before calling `solve` (to write out the model in LP format):

```
cplex.exportModel("test.lp");
```

I'd also recommend looking at the examples that are included with CPLEX (e.g., ilolpex1.cpp, etc.).